# git status find untracked files ../.merge_file_vbohis auto generated and i don't know how to git rid of

Tags: git, github, git-status

when i run the command:

```
git status
```

I find untracked files   ../.merge_file_vbohis auto generated and I don't know how to git rid of and why are they here?!

```
untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

../.merge_file_1fRTco
../.merge_file_497EAv
../.merge_file_6Wrwsj
../.merge_file_FTsrcP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure by what tool those files were generated but you could easily ignore them with `.gitignore` file. It could contain a glob pattern that will exclude those files:

```
$ echo ".merge_file_*" >> ../.gitignore
$ git add ../.gitignore
$ git status # this one should show new .gitignore file, without those merge files mentioned above
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say why they're there, but you can get rid of them with `git clean -xdf`. However, this will nuke *all* of your untracked files, so make sure you aren't deleting anything you haven't added to git but want to.

You can do a dry run (to see what will be deleted) with `git clean -xdf --dry-run`. I'd recommend doing the dry run first, and then removing the flag if you're comfortable with what will be deleted.